# What does fjac mean in scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

Consider the following code.

```
from scipy import optimize

def fun(x):
     return [x[0]  + 0.5 * (x[0] - x[1])**3 - 1.0,
             0.5 * (x[1] - x[0])**3 + x[1]]

def jac(x):
    return np.array([[1 + 1.5 * (x[0] - x[1])**2,
                      -1.5 * (x[0] - x[1])**2],
                      [-1.5 * (x[1] - x[0])**2,
                      1 + 1.5 * (x[1] - x[0])**2]])

sol = optimize.root(fun, [0, 0],method='hybr')
print(sol)
```

In particular `print(sol.fjac)` returns the following `2 x 2` matrix. Let's call it matrix `A`.

```
[[-0.9   0.44]
 [-0.44 -0.9 ]]
```

According to [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult) this is the Jacobian matrix of the function `fun` evaluated at some point.

**Question**. Exactly at which point?. More precisely what is the value of `x0` for which `jac(x0)` equals the matrix `A`?

I have given the explicit Jacobian above for testing purposes.

For example I tested `jac(sol.x)` and it it not the same  `2 x 2` matrix as above so it can't be the Jacobian evaluated at the solution. I also did `jac([0,0])` and it still does not equal the given matrix.

Any ideas?

Comment: ```FJAC is an output N by N array which contains the orthogonal
         matrix Q produced by the QR factorization of the final approx-
         imate Jacobian.``` [from here](https://www.math.utah.edu/software/minpack/minpack/hybrd.html)